# Connection to mysql works fine locally but not as AWS lambda function

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I've created a simple mySQL database that I'm trying to access data from via an AWS Lambda function.

This is a version of the code that runs fine locally:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname
});


pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // Use the connection
    connection.query("SELECT username FROM ClimbingDB.users WHERE email = 'testemail1'", function (error, results, fields) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();
    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results);

    process.exit();
  });
});
```

This is that code converted to work with AWS Lambda:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname
});


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
        // Use the connection
        connection.query("SELECT username FROM ClimbingDB.users WHERE email = 'testemail1'", function (error, results, fields) {
        // And done with the connection.
        connection.release();
        // Handle error after the release.
        if (error) return callback(error);
        else return callback(null,results);
        });
    });
};
```

Which times out with this error message:
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-07-19T17:49:04.110Z 2f3e208c-62a6-4e90-b8ec-29398780a2a6 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

I'm not sure why it doesnt seem to be able to connect. I tried adding the function to a vpc and a security group that has access to RDB's, neither of which do anything. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need:

- The Amazon RDS instance **in the same VPC** as the AWS Lambda function
- A **security group on the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`)
- A **security group on the RDS instance** (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound connections on port 3306 from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically reference `Lambda-SG` (it will turn into a security group ID in the format `sg-1234`).

You might also want to increase the timeout of the Lambda function to give it a bit more time to run.